# Basic Java calculator using functions (beginner)

Tags: java, calculator

Hey guys i'm a beginner at java still learning. I have a question about functions. So I am creating just for fun a basic calculator

```
package calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

 public void printMenu() {
    System.out.println("Basic Calculator");
    System.out.println("A. Addition");
    System.out.println("B. Subtraction");
    System.out.println("C. Multiplication");
    System.out.println("D. Division");
    System.out.println("Enter letter of operation");
}

public void enterNumbers() {
    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    int n1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    int n2 = scan.nextInt();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    calc.printMenu();
    String choice = scanner.nextLine();
    Calculator operation = new Calculator();

    switch (choice) {
        case "a":
        case "A":
            System.out.println("Addition");
            operation.enterNumbers();
    }
  }
}
```

but when i test it when i proceed to case a which is my addition  it shows this:

```
run:
Basic Calculator
A. Addition
B. Subtraction
C. Multiplication
D. Division
Enter letter of operation: 
A
Addition
Enter first number:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at calculator.scan.nextInt(scan.java:19)
    at calculator.Calculator.enterNumbers(Calculator.java:29)
    at calculator.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:46)
/Users/juancarlosraymundo/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Is there an error when I'm calling the function enterNumbers? Thank you so much I hope to learn more.

Comment: Scanner must be a field, scan don't exist

Answer (score 0):

Scanner must be a field, scan don't exist

i define scanner under class line
and change `scann` to `scanner` in `enterNumbers()` method.

```
package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

/** * * @author juancarlosraymundo */ 
public class Calculator {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public void printMenu() {
    System.out.println("Basic Calculator");
    System.out.println("A. Addition");
    System.out.println("B. Subtraction");
    System.out.println("C. Multiplication");
    System.out.println("D. Division");
    System.out.println("Enter letter of operation");
}

public void enterNumbers() {
    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    int n1 = scanner .nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    int n2 = scanner .nextInt();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    calc.printMenu();
    String choice = scanner.nextLine();
    Calculator operation = new Calculator();

    switch (choice) {
        case "a":
        case "A":
            System.out.println("Addition");
            operation.enterNumbers();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You want to add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're forgetting the declaration of `scan`.

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

right below the `public class Calculator` may do the job

Comment: Declaring a second scanner object isn't really helpful. There should be exactly one scanner object in use

Answer (score 0):

In your enterNumbers() function scan is an unknown object reference:

```
public void enterNumbers() {
    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    int n1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    int n2 = scan.nextInt();

}
```

create scanner object in above function or pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out: the problem in your code is that you are a variable named *scan* that isn't defined in your source code.

Thus the direct answer is to make *scanner* a field of your class and use that whenever you need to ask for user input (you have to avoid using more than one scanner on system. in btw).

But the real answer is: when your class has compile errors then **fix** them. Running code that doesn't fully compile leads to exactly such problems. Sometimes it is helpful that IDEs such as eclipse allow running incomplete code, but avoid doing that when you are a newbie.

Comment: Can I message you or something to ask help. Thanks

Comment: Please understand that this isn't programming school where you get free tutor service. My personal recommendation: step back from android for a few days and focus on java basics. Beyond that I will be really busy today, few chances to have time for chats.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Calculator {
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public void printMenu() {
    System.out.println("Basic Calculator");
    System.out.println("A. Addition");
    System.out.println("B. Subtraction");
    System.out.println("C. Multiplication");
    System.out.println("D. Division");
    System.out.println("Enter letter of operation");
}

public void enterNumbers() {
    System.out.println("Enter first number:");
    int n1 = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second number:");
    int n2 = scanner.nextInt();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    calc.printMenu();
    char choice = scanner.next().charAt(0);//switch cant work with string //,declare choice as character
    Calculator operation = new Calculator();

    switch (choice) {//switch cant work with string 
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        System.out.println("Addition");
        operation.enterNumbers();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: switch cant work with string ,it only works with enum or integer

Comment: Starting with java 7 switch can also use strings.